# Multi-channel audio coming from wrong speakers

Tags: sound, speakers, 22.10

I just installed Ubuntu 22.10 coming from Windows 11, and I'm trying to set up my audio options.  I have a 5.1 speaker system connected by analog output from a SoundBlasterX AE-5 sound card.  The rear-left sound is coming out of the center channel, The center channel is coming out of the front-left speaker, rear-right is coming out of the subwoofer, the subwoofer is coming out of the front-right.

The front-right and front-left sound is coming from the correct speakers, so there are multiple audio channels coming out of the same speakers.  I've tried moving the physical connections to every possible output with no luck.

Also, and I'm not sure if this is supposed to work like this, but when I drag the System Sounds slider, the subwoofer slider moves as well.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of sound system and how exactly are the cables configured? Also what audio source(s) are you using to test this? What application do you use to play audio and what media are you using to test/diagnose the issue? In Windows were you using any other software to configure your audio? For example, proprietary software from Creative or proprietary software for your other audio components?

Comment: It's a Logitech 5.1 system connected by three analog minipin connectors.  In Windows I was using the Soundblaster software, but that was just to modify optional settings, it worked just fine with the Windows driver and configuration.  On Ubuntu I just went into the Settings and tried to configure the audio settings to output 5.1 and test the results from there.  You know, clicking the speaker icon and hearing which speaker the sound came from.